# How to calculate from 12345678987654321 to 1.23457e16

Tags: notation, computational-mathematics

I wrote 2 number in the question title. How can i convert number 12345678987654321 to 1.23457e16 ? I researched a lot but i couldn't find the how calculate e value what is the mathematically  rules of the could you help me out?

Comment: "AeB" simply means $A \cdot 10^B$. Google "scientific notation".

Comment: So you mean e is the 10 but according to example number that i asked in the question your rule not working i think. I don't follow what you mean actually . I came out with scientific notation but actually i couldn't find the steps for the calculating

Comment: I reached this result when i multiply 111111111 * 111111111 = 12345678987654321 but in the Iphone calculator i came up with 1.23457e16 so i couldn't figure it out...

Comment: For example let's say we want to convert $1234$ into scientific notation. $\textbf{Basically}$ you count the number of digit (here are $4$), put the decimal point after the digit (Here between $1$ and $2$) and set the exponent to be the number of digit minus 1. Here $1234 = 1.234e3 = 1.234 \cdot 10^3$.

Comment: So according to you explanation if we want to convert 12345678987654321 there is 17 digits so we have to put 16 of the end and the result will be 1.234567e16 right? but why i see the 123457e16 in ios calculator ?

Comment: @KemalEkren They rounded $1.234567$ to $1.23457$

Comment: They definitelly =) Thanks for the answer finally i got the whole thing